# Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange error loading web page

Tags: wildfly

I'm trying to create a web-application via Maven and IntellijIDEA, which is going to write data in PostgreSQL data-base using EJB and CDI.
My problem is - I can't even start cause my app doesnt load JSF pages.
I have a dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<name>webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My index.xhtml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    WEBAPP
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Add Entity"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But when i'm trying to load localhost:8080/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index.xhtml i'm getting error:

```
  00:17:10,782 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-18) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index.xhtml request {Connection=[keep-alive], Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/47.0.2631.80], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1], Server=[WildFly/11], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[639], Date=[Thu, 21 Sep 2017 21:17:10 GMT]}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [1087] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:142)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:163)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:248)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:154)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2042)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:473)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

00:17:11,088 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-19) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index.xhtml request {Connection=[keep-alive], Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/47.0.2631.80], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1], Server=[WildFly/11], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[638], Date=[Thu, 21 Sep 2017 21:17:11 GMT]}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [1087] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:142)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:163)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:248)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:154)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2042)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:473)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using JBoss(now WildFly) as app-server.

MyCDI.class:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyCDI {

    @EJB
    MyEJB myEJB;

    public void createEntity(){
        myEJB.createEntity();
    }

}
```

MyEJB.class:

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;


@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyEJB {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "examplePU")
    public EntityManager entityManager;


    public MyEntity createEntity(){
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.setName("EntityName");
        entityManager.persist(myEntity);

        return myEntity;
    }
}
```

MyEntity.class:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing JSF, nothing maven, nothing postgress related in the (uncomplete?)  stacktrace. It is all just wildfly stuff. And that tag is missing from your 'tags'. I corrected that for you. Your _"JSF page doesn't loading"_ is your end-user experience problem (without the 'jsf' part). Your developer problem is in the stacktrace. I corrected all this for you

Comment: Try to clear the cookies in your browser.  There is a bad string in there somehow (`An invalid control character [1087] was present in the cookie value or attribute`)

Comment: Well, i cleared cache,cookies(and so on) from browser still getting same problem(btw im having same issue in all browsers).And i added full stacktrace(or i think so), unfortunately it doesn't tell much for me.

Comment: Are you creating a cookie? It looks like it's seeing a value or attribute with the `п` character. I do see the language is set to `ru-RU,ru;`. AIUI the value attribute needs to be US-ASCII, e.g. 32-127.

Comment: @James At this point, i did't create any cookie manually.I added all my classes to question. And i'm not using any Russian characters in my code(at least i dont see them :) ).And it would be great if you specify how to change that value to US-ASCII.(shoud i just replace all encoding values to ASCII ?)

Comment: If you're not creating a cookie this is likely a bug. What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: I'm using wildfly-11.0.0.Should i re-install it?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins You was right. It was a bug.I've re-installed my wildfly and now it works perfectly.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We've had similar problems today and found that Umlauts (äöü) are causing that UT000173 problem. In our case we try to remember the username of the user in the cookie. By avoiding this we could work around it.

We've introduced this problem by updating from JBoss EAP v7.0.7 to v7.0.9 lately.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem this week and couldn;t fix it for 4 days. Finally, I found that cyrillic symbols in the name of your windows PC could be the reason of this problem.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using `spring boot` and server `tomcat`: open port 8080 on proxy gateway (can call directly).
**You should to private port 8080**.

Comment: This answer is confusing and I'm not sure it addresses the question